# Is reputation a resource to be used?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I was wondering if reputation is meant more as a "resource to be used" or as something that should steadily increase as your experience grows? I ask this as recently on Stack Overflow my reputation has been dropping because I have been posting a lot of bounties.

Is this how I'm meant to use my reputation, or should I really be trying to get to those higher amounts of reputation?

Comment: You don't **have to** do anything. It's your rep. If you never want to offer bounties, don't. If that's valuable to you, do. Look at this [low rep Meta user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160410/minitech) for example. Then look at his bounties.

Comment: @Bart in fairness though, his privileges aren't tied to rep since he can do everything, so it is not a perfect example.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's true. But it doesn't change the **have to**.

Comment: A better (none moderator) example might be http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/code-mocker with 228 offered bounties and three digit rep.

Comment: Guys, you really downvote too easily!

Comment: I think that too fast voting for close or downvoting should be discouraged. Downvoting is not a fight or a game for child. Have a look at how many question closed for dup are better than the first question.

Comment: I think marking as a duplicate question that are not strictly the same or that are more constructive than the first one, should cost in reputation to the voters.

Comment: @Sam My guess is that the downvotes were for the use of the word "karma". In which case they seem unwarranted. Also I agree not really a dupe. This is discussing one specific aspect of pros and cons of hoarding rep vs spending it as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah, I don't agree with the dupe here. Voted to reopen. I get the point, but it does not answer the underlying question here.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you don't **have to** do anything. It's your rep. If you never want to offer bounties, don't. If that's valuable to you, do.

Of course there is the issue of privileges. More reputation gets you more privileges. How important those are to you is up to you. While we call them privileges, they are to some extent more ways for you to clean up the crap of others. If that is not your thing and not where you wish to take your participation, you could always set yourself an upper limit. Get as much rep as necessary to obtain those privileges you want, and spend the rest. Or just go for 20k and cap it at that.

We don't really care about your reputation. If you have excellent contributions, but are a <1k user due to bounties, you are by no means doing something wrong.